# How to close a stage after a certain amount of time JavaFX

Tags: java, while-loop, javafx, stage

I'm currently working with two controller classes.

In Controller1 it creates a new stage that opens on top of the main one.

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Controller2.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Now once that stage is open, I want it to stay open for about 5 seconds before closing itself.

Within Controller2, I've tried implementing something like

```
long mTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = mTime + 5000; // 5 seconds 

while (System.currentTimeMillis() > end) 
{
      //close this stage  
}
```

but I have no idea what to put inside the while loop to close it. I've tried all sorts and nothing works.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a [`PauseTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html):

```
PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
delay.setOnFinished( event -> stage.close() );
delay.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it your way, this would work:

```
long mTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = mTime + 5000; // 5 seconds 

while (mTime < end) 
{
    mTime = System.currentTimeMilis();
} 
stage.close();
```

You need to save your stage into a variable.
Maybe it is better to run that in a Thread, so that you can do something within the 5 seconds.
Another way would be to run a Thread.sleep(5000); and this would also be more performant than the while loop.

Comment: If you use these kind of techniques, you would *have* to run that in a thread, else the contents of the stage would not display. Moreover, you would have to wrap `stage.close()` in a `Platform.runLater(...)` as that has to be executed on the FX Application Thread. It's easier to use a `PauseTransition`.

Answer (score 0):

This code sets the text of a TextArea element and makes it visible for a certain amount of time. It essentially creates a pop up system message:

```
public static TextArea message_text=new TextArea();

final static String message_text_style="-fx-border-width: 5px;-fx-border-radius: 10px;-fx-border-style: solid;-fx-border-color: #ff7f7f;";

public static int timer;
public static void system_message(String what,int set_timer)
{

    timer=set_timer;

    message_text.setText(what);
    message_text.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1;"+message_text_style);

    Thread system_message_thread=new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(timer);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {

            }

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
            {

                public void run()
                {

                    message_text.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 0;"+message_text_style);

                }   

            });

        }   

    });

    system_message_thread.start();

}
```

This solution is completely general. You can change the setStyle methods to any code that you want. You can open and close a stage if you like.